# SQL Server stored procedure passing datepart year as a parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, datepart

I was wondering if anyone could help please, I've got the below procedure, I'm trying to enable it so that an end user can pass the year portion of the date only and it will query based on that parameter so at the moment I'm querying between `ContractDate.ContractDate >= 01/01/2015 AND <= 31/12/2015` but I would like our users to be able to enter '2016' for example into a text box as a parameter that is passed and would update the year part of the above criteria querying based on this but leaving the month and day portion intact, this way they can enter

I'm quite a novice when it comes to sql so any help is gladly appreciated.

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT 
    dbo.Users.LoginName, 
    CAST(DATENAME(m, dbo.ContractDate.ContractDate) AS varchar) AS DatePeriod, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.Contract.Contract = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Contract, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.contract.contract = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Permanent
FROM
    dbo.ContractSkill 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Users 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Contract ON dbo.Users.UserId = dbo.Contract.UserId   
INNER JOIN
    dbo.ContractDate ON dbo.Contract.ContractId =   dbo.ContractDate.ContractId 
    ON dbo.ContractSkill.ContractId = dbo.Contract.ContractId
WHERE        
    (dbo.ContractDate.DNS = 0) 
    AND (dbo.ContractSkill.SkillId = 30960)    
    AND (dbo.ContractDate.ContractDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-01-01  00:00:00', 102)) 
    AND (dbo.ContractDate.ContractDate <= convert(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))
GROUP BY 
    CAST(DATENAME(m, dbo.ContractDate.ContractDate) AS varchar),
    MONTH(dbo.ContractDate.ContractDate), dbo.Users.LoginName
    ORDER BY MONTH(dbo.ContractDate.ContractDate)
```

Comment: You can use `Year(dbo.Contract .ContractDate) = 2015` instead

Comment: It looks like you are missing part of the Join for ContractSkill to Users

Comment: Why are you using top 100 percent?  I think you can remove that too.

Comment: Hi Shell, If I use that will it run the query from the start of 2015 to the end of 2015? If so would I be able to pass #Year as a parameter and say that Year(contract.contractdate) = #Year

Comment: @GemmaScully yup, if you want to show all data for particular year then you just need to pass a parameter for year only. ie. `@Contract_Year tinyint`.

Comment: `Where Year(dbo.Contract.ContractDate) = @Contract_Year` just like this.

Comment: @Shell  I was over thinking this a bit :-/  You should post that as the answer

Comment: Perfect - thank you so much both!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you will be adding a parameter to your function through which the selected year is being provided, then just add that parameter and:

1. Declare two variables to be used in the select statement whose type is `DATE`,
2. Add the following assignments:

   ```
   SET @YourStartVariable = CONVERT(DATETIME,CONCAT(P_Passed_Year,'-01-01 00:00:00'),102);
   SET @YourEndtVariable  = CONVERT(DATETIME,CONCAT(P_Passed_Year,'-31-12 23:59:59'),102);
   ```
3. Use these variable in your query, meaning that instead of:

   ```
   (dbo.ContractDate.ContractDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME,'2015-01-01 00:00:00', 102))
   AND (dbo.ContractDate.ContractDate <= convert(DATETIME,'2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))
   ```

   you would have:

   ```
   (dbo.ContractDate.ContractDate >=  @YourStartVariable)
   AND (dbo.ContractDate.ContractDate <=  @YourEndVariable)
   ```

That is.

Your original upper limit was YYYY-12-31 00:00:00 and I'm guessing it should be YYYY-12-31 **23:59:59**.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve this thing..

---

***1st one is very simple by passing a parameter for Year only***

```
@Contract_Year tityint
```

then placing a where condition with function `Year()`.

```
Where Year(dbo.Contract.ContractDate) = @Contract_Year
```

---

***And the second one is to create two separate variable for From Date and To Date.***

I would recommend to use this method if you have created index on `ContractDate` field. B'coz, index will not be considered if you use the field inside any function (ie. Year(), Month() or Day()).

**Paremter**

```
@Contract_Year Char(4)
```

**Stored Procedure Code**

```
Declare @from_Date DateTime = Cast(@Contract_Year + '-01-01' As DateTime);
Declare @to_Date DateTime = Cast(@Contract_Year + '-12-31 23:59:59' As DateTime);
```

**Use the above variable in Where clause**

```
Where (dbo.Contract.ContractDate Between @from_Date and @to_Date)
```